# Printing elements of an array in Reverse, but only one element will print

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to print the elements of an array forward and backwards using for loops. I have been able to print the elements forward however, when I attempt to print them backwards only one element will print.

Here is my code:

```
public class NineInts 
{  
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        int x;
        int i;
        int[] numbers = new int[] {10, 15, 19, 23, 26, 29, 31, 34, 38};
        for(x = 0; x < numbers.length; ++x)
            System.out.print(numbers[x] + " ");
        for(i = numbers.length - 1; i > 0; --i);
            System.out.print(numbers[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

The second for loop only prints one element. I have tried a few things I have seen on this website about reverse array's but to no avail.

Comment: `for(i = numbers.length - 1; i > 0; --i);` has a **typo**. Remove the semicolon at the end of the line. That terminates the loop. Learn to use an autoindenter. And **always** use braces with loops and ifs.

Comment: Yes, as @ElliottFrisch said, you have error in your second for llop. You are terminating it without printing. put the print statement inside second loop

Comment: Thank you so much... I don't know why I didn't realize that error...I feel sheepish thanks again for that.

Answer (score 0):

You have added a colin after the second for loop. Remove the same.

```
for(i = numbers.length - 1; i > 0; --i)
```